# Why setHTML("<table><tr>..</tr></table>"); but then getHTML(); return "<table><tbody><tr>..</tr></tbody></table>" (Gwt)?

Tags: gwt

I don't understand how Gwt `setHTML & getHTML` work. It doesn't seem to be consistent.

Let see this example:

```
myInlineHtml.setHTML(SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant("<table><tr><td>Test</td></tr></table>"));
System.out.println(myInlineHtml.getHTML());
```

Output: `"<table><tbody><tr><td>Test</td></tr></tbody></table>"`

Clearly when we set the html for `myInlineHtml` we don't have `<tbody></tbody>`, but when we `getHTML` from `myInlineHtml` then Gwt include `<tbody></tbody>`.

Why does that's happen because it can be confusing when you want to get the Html value and you thought it has the same value I the time we set it but it hasn't?

> Does this happen independently from browsers or dpendently from
>   browsers? cos that is serious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how HTML is parsed (how browsers are expected to parse it).

In HTML 4, [`TABLE` was defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-TABLE) (in terms of SGML) as requiring a `TBODY` child element, and that [`TBODY` is defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-TBODY) with both the start and end tags being optional.

In HTML5 (which codifies how browsers actually parse HTML), this is the same: when building a `table`, if the browser finds a `tr`, then it [inserts a `tbody`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-intable) element before parsing the `tr` as if there were a `tbody` initially.

Comment: But the most important thing is Does getHTML return the same value in all browsers? or it returns differently depending on the browsers?

Comment: @Tum Why don't you just test it?

Comment: i had 3 browsers IE, Chrome & FF not sure which version, but seem all these browsers act the same, Any way I have to change my program to not depend on getHTML. Thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Browsers try to format the html properly even if you omit certain keys or parameters. Most modern browsers will accept almost anything you pass it without complaining much, but instead of inserting exactly what you intended, it will interpret what you meant and insert valid HTML.

Therefore, is is perfectly valid to create a table without specifiyng a tbody node, but the browser will supply it for you. Once you use `getHTML()` you are accessing the parsed, well formatted tags.

Comment: Does this happen independently from browsers or dependently from browsers? cos that is serious.

Comment: So getHTML return value based on the Browser or based on the Gwt mechanism?

Comment: It might be somewhat related to the browser, but I wouldn't think so. I believe it's more related to the doctype declaration. XHTML enforces much syntax that html5 doesn't care about. I'm not experienced in GWT, but jQuery behaves similarly when dealing with prior and parsed html. If you insert a self closed div ```jQuery(element).html('<div id="mydiv"/>');``` and retrieve the content afterwards, it will be a valid empty div ```<div id="mydiv"></div>```.  In your case I'd try to always insert properly formatted html for the doctype I'm using. If gwt enforces the tbody, then feed it a tbody.

Comment: "It might be somewhat related to the browser" that is serious cos it can cause error in programming, you get different values from different browsers

Comment: You need to find a way for your code to work even if there's minor differences in the DOM structure. For example, when using css or xpath selectors, you can address the first table's tr independent of it being enclosed in tbody tags. That's why jQuery became so popular for DOM manipulation. It abstracted getters, setters and listeners to spare you the trouble of adapting to different browsers.